# Update statement to increase by increment 1 is not executing when returning to index.php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to increase a value by increment 1, which is stored in a database. 
However, when the add.php file has ran and I go back to the index.php file, the value remains the same without any increasing increment.

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <p><a href = "add.php">Click to update score</a></p>
    </head>
</html>

<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "friends");

    if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
        die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli -> connect_errno);
    }

    $results = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT score FROM user LIMIT 1");
    while ($row = $results -> fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['score'];
    }

?>
```

**add.php**

```
<?php
    // Connect to the database with '$mysqli' as the connection variable name
    $mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "friends");

    //Check connection
    if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
        die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli -> connect_errno);
    }

     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 1");
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


     //Update Statement
     $stmt = "UPDATE score SET score = score + 1 WHERE id = 1";


     //Result notice
     echo "Update completed.."; 
     //Link back to index.php
     echo "<a href = 'index.php'>Back to likes</a>";

?>
```

Comment: Because you are attempting to update **table** called "score".

Comment: @tereško it's perfectly possible to have a table called score with a column called score within it. As far as I can see, the problem is that the update statement is declared but never executed.

Comment: @ADyson yes, but in the index file he is selecting it from table called "user"

Comment: @ tereško i have changed it to  $stmt = "UPDATE user SET score = score + 1 WHERE id = 1"; but it is still not working

Comment: @FabioWolf it's because you only declare a string called $stmt, you never actually send the query to the database

Comment: ... oh, I actually missed that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not actually running the update query. You were just setting your statement in a variable.

```
//Update Statement

$stmt = "UPDATE score SET score = score + 1 WHERE id = 1";
$mysqli->query($stmt);
```

Another option is:

```
$stmt = "UPDATE score SET score = score + 1 WHERE id = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $stmt);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on string

Comment: @FabioWolf That's really really weird, try the other approach I've just put above.

Comment: The error message disappeared but the values still do not update.

Comment: Your second option does not work either. I think there is something wrong with the UPDATE statement.

Comment: @FabioWolf Can you try targeting different `id`? I actually tried it with a dummy table and it works.

Comment: Sorry, @Robin Carlo Catacutan I had a syntax error. Thank you very much!

Comment: @FabioWolf the table name is wrong in the query. It should be user instead of score